# Python pyodbc write to Microsoft Azure SQL Database Error

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, dataframe, azure, pyodbc

I used to use Python pyodbc to write data to sql server Express, but Express reached 10B max disk, so I have to switch to Microsoft Azure SQL Database, I encountered below error

**ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.syscharsets' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.**

the code I using

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.111.111;DATABASE=MYDB;UID=' + keyring.get_password("local", "UID") + ';PWD=' + keyring.get_password("local", "PWD") + ';')

cursor = conn.cursor()

for index, row in df_add.iterrows():
    
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable([ID],[CreateDate]) values(?,?)",row['ID'], row['CreateDate']) 

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: That's a _very old_ ODBC driver that ships with Windows.  Try a current one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft how to modify my python to code to point to that new driver? thanks

Comment: Just change the driver name. Doc'd here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: it works, you should tell me after download it, i need to install it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the Microsoft team's answer, here's the step.

1.download the new driver and install in your computer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

2. modify this part in my code , reference [python code to connect from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16)

   DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}

[image]